# Synchronous muxing and demuxing of klv data using gstreamer

Tags: c++, gstreamer, klvdata

I am trying to achieve synchronous muxing and demuxing of klv data using gstreamer. As per my understanding, the current version of getreamer (GStreamer Core Library version 1.16.3) and the plugin tsdemux does not support synchronous muxing and demuxing. It would be of tremendous help if I could find answers to the following questions:

1. Is there a way I can use to achieve this using other gstreamer plugins?
2. If synchronous klv isn't supported by existing frameworks and plugins, are there any alternative methods to achieve synchronous KLV muxing and demuxing, perhaps by writing my own custom code? If yes, is there any resource to detail the steps to be followed?

Thanks in advance!